# Use a link for updating with edits/added answers

Tags: feature-request, design

Might sound stupid but the buttons used for updating edited posts are created by a `div` tag, which is not recognised as a link by keyboard-oriented browsers/extensions.
That's somehow annoying when you're used to "clicking" links using the keyboard, at least for me.
I'd like to ask (if not too insolent) for a little update where a link is used either instead of or inside that *update* button so that it's recognized as a clickable element.

(having in mind especially the vimium extension and the vimbrowser... browser)

Comment: Now I'm seeing the vimium question in the hot meta posts group, but since I don't see my problem there, I'll leave the question open.

Comment: I'll add a note here: If you enable keyboard shortcuts that are built-in to Stack Overflow, there _is_ an "edit" option... But I've been testing it for a couple minutes, and it doesn't seem to actually work. If that worked properly, then it could be a possible way to address your issue.